# how can i view a gitlab issue board that spans multiple projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8, gitlab-7, scrumboard

## background

I've been a religious user for github/zenhub for quite a while. We recently moved our repos to gitlab for many reasons, including free pipelines, security, more flexible groups etc.

## Problem

[Zenhub](http://zenhub.com/) is a [greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) app that's added to github, one of its features is the scrumboard that's similar to gitlab's native [issue board](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/issueboard/). One of the amazing things about zenhub [scrumboard](https://www.zenhub.com/product) is that it allows you to put many repos on the same board (I recall jira had the same thing).

## question

Is there a way to do this on gitlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside a third-party like [kanban.leanlabs.io](http://kanban.leanlabs.io/), recent GitLab releases do integrate a more sophisticated issue management.

See "[Announcing The GitLab Issue Board](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/08/22/announcing-the-gitlab-issue-board/) " ([presented here](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/issueboard/))
But it might be limited to only the current repo.

---

Note that with [GitLab 13.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/11/22/gitlab-13-6-released/#group-level-management-of-project-integrations) (November 2020), this is no longer limited to a repository:

> ### Group-level management of project integrations
>
> In GitLab 13.3, we added the ability to [enable an integration across an entire instance](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/08/22/gitlab-13-3-released/#instance-level-project-integration-management-for-external-services). With GitLab 13.6, that feature is being expanded to allow integrations to be managed at the group level as well!
>
> Group owners can now add an integration to a group, and that integration will be inherited by all projects under that group. This has the potential for saving massive amounts of time, as many organizations have specific integrations that they want rolled out to every project they create.
>
> A great example of this is using our [Jira integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html). If you’re using Jira, it’s almost always across the whole company. Some of these companies have *thousands of projects* and therefore had to configure each and every one of those integrations individually.
>
> With group-level management of project integrations, you can add the integration at each parent group, reducing the amount of configuration required by orders of magnitude!
>
> Read more in [our announcement on the GitLab blog](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/11/19/integration-management/).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_6/project-integration-inheriting-settings.png -- Group-level management of project integrations]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/project_integration_management.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2543).

Answer (score 2):

In GitLab [issues and merge requests within a group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/group/#issues-and-merge-requests-within-a-group) display a collection of issues and merge requests from all projects below them.

And they also have an [Issue Board](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/issue_board.html) available, which aggregates the issues from the projects within the given group. This is currently not reflected in the documentation, and could be well worth a Pull Request in [doc/user/group/index.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/group/index.md) and [doc/user/project/issue_board.md](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/project/issue_board.md).

Using this together with group labels and milestones, which also span across all subprojects, you can create the desired board view.

Answer (score 0):

I do use github/zenhub in the past. https://gitboard.co is the zenhub alternative for gitlab. Which shows all your issue and merge request in one simple dashboard across multiple projects.